# Spring RestTemplate can not convert json response

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I have url - `http://hzhzhz`

return json

```
{
    "someField": 3,
    "datesField": ["2017-08-19",
    "2017-08-20",
    "2017-08-26",
    "2018-12-30"]
}
```

I create models

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
private class Response{
    private int someField;
    private DatesField datesField;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
private class DatesField{
    private List<String> strings;
}
```

I create

```
ResponseforObject = restTemplate.getForObject("http://hzhzhz", Response.class);
```

Amd I get error:

```
Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class mypackeg.Response] and content type [text/html;charset=utf-8]
```

Comment: Try to get the response in a String and see what the service is returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `"http://hzhzhz"` call returns HTML which cannot be converted to the mypackeg.Response class.

Could be URL is wrong or it produces wrong content type (HTML instead of expected JSON or XML). To fix try to return String.class and check what exactly in the string.

One more possible reason is permission denied which returns access denied HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Change the http://hzhzhz endpoint to return

```
content type = 'application/json'
```

If the http://hzhzhz is made by spring use this in the request mapping

```
produces = "application/json"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use spring controller, you should change produces as "application/json"