# RestTemplate return json string like html. How can convert it to Model?

Tags: html, json, spring, jackson, resttemplate

I have URL `http://test/getUser`

This uerl return json string like html. When I call this url in browser I get JSON but from `restTemplate` I get this JSON like `String`

I do it:

```
 String forObject = restTemplate.getForObject("http://test/getUser", String.class);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Users users = mapper.readValue(forObject, Users.class);
```

But I want next:

```
Users users = restTemplate.getForObject("http://test/getUser", Users.class);
```

Comment: Do you have any exception when you use second variant?

Comment: @ Sergey Yes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758437/spring-resttemplate-can-not-convert-json-response